# Iterative equations in R

Tags: r, math, equation

I have the equation **C.sul.f = C.sul.i + (R * C.sil.i) / (1 + R/D)**, where *C.sul.i* = 200000, *C.sil.i* = 100, *R* = 100, and *D* = 2130.

The calculation requires that the for every iteration from 1:100000, the *C.sul.f* from the previous iteration is used for the *C.sul.i* of the current iteration. Essentially,

Iteration 1 --> C.sul.**f1** = C.sul.**i** + (R * C.sil.i) / (1 + R/D)

Iteration 2 --> C.sul.**f2** = C.sul.**f1** + (R * C.sil.i) / (1 + R/D)

Iteration 3 --> C.sul.**f3** = C.sul.**f2** + (R * C.sil.i) / (1 + R/D)

.

.

Iteration n --> C.sul.**fn** = C.sul.**fn-1** + (R * C.sil.i) / (1 + R/D)

Could I please get some help how I would structure this script in R

I appreciate any help.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3):

This is the archetype of problem `Reduce` solves:

```
c_sul_i <- 200000
c_sil_i <- 100
R <- 100
D <- 2130

Reduce(
  f = function(x, y) x + (R * c_sil_i) / (1 + R/D),
  x = 1:5,
  init = c_sul_i + (R * c_sil_i) / (1 + R/D),
  accumulate = TRUE
  )
# [1] 209551.6 219103.1 228654.7 238206.3 247757.8 257309.4
```

**PS:** Note that for example purposes I only computed the first 5 values. For your case just swap `1:5` with `1:100000`.

Comment: Thank you for your response @niko

Answer (score 2):

niko has an excellent solution using `Reduce`, but for your example (and for all series) I recommend first applying a bit of series reduction to see if there's a simple general solution.

### More Math, Faster Code

In your series, the only recursive element is effectively a constant value added to the previous one.  If you expand it out, it becomes fairly obvious:

C.sul.f1 = C.sul.i + (R * C.sil.i) / (1 + R/D)

C.sul.f2 = C.sul.i + (R * C.sil.i) / (1 + R/D) + (R * C.sil.i) / (1 + R/D)

C.sul.f3 = C.sul.i + (R * C.sil.i) / (1 + R/D) + (R * C.sil.i) / (1 + R/D) + (R * C.sil.i) / (1 + R/D)

in general:

C.sul.fn = C.sul.i + n * ((R * C.sil.i) / (1 + R/D))

So for the most efficient function, I recommend:

```
c_sul_i <- 200000
c_sil_i <- 100
R <- 100
D <- 2130

C.sul.fn <- function(n) {
     return(C.sul.i + n * (R * C.sil.i) / (1 + R/D) )
}

sapply(1:100000,C.sul.fn)
```

Or, if you prefer single line implementation:

```
sapply(1:100000,function(x) {C.sul.i + x * (R * C.sil.i) / (1 + R/D)})
```

Comment: Sharp thinking, but for even more performance consider `c_sul_i + (1:n) * (R * c_sil_i) / (1 + R/D)` which is fully vectorised.

Comment: Thank you for your response @SirTain!

Answer (score 0):

If you like to have a recursion answer, you can try defining a user function `f` like below

```
f <- function(n) {
  if (n==1) return(c.sul.i + (R * c.sil.i) / (1 + R/D))
  f(n-1) + (R * c.sil.i) / (1 + R/D)
}
```

---

For efficiency considerations, answer by [@SirTain](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65955380/12158757) using a math solution is the best.

Comment: Thank you @ThomasIsCoding for your follow up response.